# How to display multiple date ranges between a date-range Jquery

Tags: jquery

Hi I have a date ranger picker on this I want to display all the date ranges which is defined for a particular date-range as this:

Suppose my date range is: 01/01/2017-01/07/2017
and I have an array all the dates which is defined between for above date-range in db.So the array is like:

$sub_dates = ['01/01/2017','02/01/2017',.......till 01/07/2017];

So if I click on date range on date-range picker I need to show all these defined dates ($sub_dates ) on it.

```
var sub_dates = ['01/01/2017','02/01/2017',.......till 01/07/2017];
  $('.lot-calander1').daterangepicker({
    beforeShowDay: function(date){
    var string = $.daterangepicker.formatDate('yy-mm-dd', date);
    return [ sub_dates.indexOf(string) == -1 ]
 }  
});
```

But it is not displaying these date on date-range picker. please assist what could be the issue

Thanks advance

Answer (score 4):

```js
$(function() {
  var sub_dates = ['01/01/2017','01/03/2017','01/25/2017', '02/01/2017'];
  var sub_dates_date = sub_dates.map(function(b) {
    return +(new Date(b));
  });

  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    isInvalidDate: function(a) {
      return sub_dates_date.indexOf(+(new Date(a))) < 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.daterangepicker td.available {
 color: red;
 background-color: blue;
}

.daterangepicker td.available.start-date, .daterangepicker td.available.end-date {
 color: green;
 background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />
<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2017 - 01/31/2017" />
```

Please Note: *You can change the color as you want*.

Hope It will help you.

Answer (score 1):

This solution uses 'invalidDate' to check against the array of dates and disable them. For simplicity and also comparison purpose we create a new array for the string of dates and make them `integers`. You can replace this method as necessary.

```js
$(function() {
  var sub_dates = ['01/01/2017','01/03/2017','01/25/2017', '02/01/2017'];
  var sub_dates_date = sub_dates.map(function(b) {
    return +(new Date(b));
  });

  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
    isInvalidDate: function(a) {
      return sub_dates_date.indexOf(+(new Date(a))) < 0;
    }
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2017 - 01/31/2017" />
```

Let us know.

Comment: how can I highlighted each dates with different colors,for a particular range.??

Comment: lol, that's another requirement..which dates did you want to highlight ? the stirked out ones or the valid ones ?

Comment: The valid dates, but I need different colour for each array,I have multiple date-range picker with multiple date date blocks. Ex. Date block 1 has Range from 01/01/2017 - 01/30/2017 and under it I have 2 types of date within this range Type1 (array('01/01/2017-01/05/2017','01/05/2017-01/20/2017')) and Type2 (array('01/21/2017-01/25/2017','01/26/2017-01/28/2017')). So need color1 for Type1 and colour2 for Type2.

Comment: Your requirement seems to be achievable. But it's quite difficult to understand the structure and give a proper answer. It is worth creating a separate question, with more details and may be real response data of the date array(s).@SunilRawat

Answer (score 0):

You can use `minDate` and `maxDate` options

```js
$(function() {
  $('input[name="daterange"]').daterangepicker({
      locale: {
         format: 'MM/DD/YYYY'
      },
      minDate: '01/01/2017',
      maxDate: '01/07/2017'
  });
});
```

```html
<!-- Include Required Prerequisites -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/momentjs/latest/moment.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap/3/css/bootstrap.css" />
 
<!-- Include Date Range Picker -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/bootstrap.daterangepicker/2/daterangepicker.css" />

<input type="text" name="daterange" value="01/01/2017 - 01/07/2017" />
```