# Jquery compare time greater/smaller then for forenoon and afternoon in 24h Format

Tags: jquery, validation, time

unfortunately i wasn't lucky with search so will try to place my issue. Sorry if this may be a doublicate - im honestly didnt found any similar topic.

In my Form i have time fields for business hours from-to like

```
<input type="text" id="timeStart" />
<input type="text" id="timeEnd" />
```

all values appearing in hh:mm format.

So i need now to validate end time is not smaller then start time. My issue is that values startTime 09:00 (9am same day morning) and let say EndTime 01:00 (1am next day night) will not validated correctly - on comparing it shows me then 01:00 is smaller then 09:00 and disallow, what is logicaly correct as one is smaller as nine, but it belongs to next day and therefore should be valid.

My custom validation Method:

```
$.validator.addMethod(
            "ClosingTimeGreaterAsOpeningTime",
            function (value, element) {
                var timeOpen = $("#timeStart").val();

                if (value != '' && value.length > 0) {
                    if (value <= timeOpen)
                        return false                    
                    else
                        return true
                }
                return true;
            },
            "End time can't be greater/equal Start time."
        );
```

So my question is, if there is an proper method for such validation by suggestion, that opening hour may be earliest 5am and everithing above (00:00 to 04:59) belongs to next day and should be greater then start time?

as this are Business Hours, possible provided values are in half hour rythm: 09:00 - 09:30 - 10:00 - 10:30 and so on.

My idea is to create an array with exception times (00:00 to 04:59), but im not sure how to compare then due t my newby skills in this.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Cheers
Alex

Comment: If all the user is entering is a time, then you cannot validate this because there's no way of knowing what day the times refer to - as you state that they can in fact cross dates.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to display multiple date ranges between a date-range Jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43661080/how-to-display-multiple-date-ranges-between-a-date-range-jquery)

Comment: Unfortunately nope.

Comment: I just understood, that without to have date this is simply not possible. Sp this is obsolete now. Im just not sure how to close/delete post there.